# Twisted errors in Scrapy spider

Tags: twisted, web-crawler, scrapy

When I run the spider from the Scrapy tutorial I get these error messages:

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 374, in fireEvent DeferredList(beforeResults).addCallback(self._continueFiring)  

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 195, in addCallback callbackKeywords=kw)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 186, in addCallbacks self._runCallbacks()

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 328, in_runCallbacks self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kw)
```

--- `<exception caught here>` ---

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 387, in _continueFiring callable(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 356, in listenTCP p.startListening()

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 858, in startListening raise CannotListenError, (self.interface, self.port, le) twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:6023: [Errno 10048] 

Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Does anyone know what they are and how I can get rid of them?

Thanks

Comment: You should format the traceback in your question better so that it's easier to read.  Try indenting it all 4 spaces.  Also, make sure you include the whole thing.  It looks like you probably left off a line or two at the end.

Comment: This is very worrying, I read the title and knew exactly what the question was about. :-}

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the post, it's look better now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you're running two Scrapy process simultaneously with telnet console enabled?.

If you want to run more than one Scrapy process at the same time, you must disable (or, at least, change the port) of web and telnet consoles.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was running, the scrapy shell and prompt at the same time. Now I only get the deprecation warnings.