# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor is ignoring allowed links

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Please take a look at [this spider example](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) in Scrapy documentation. The explanation is:

> This spider would start crawling example.com’s home page, collecting category links, and item links, parsing the latter with the parse_item method. For each item response, some data will be extracted from the HTML using XPath, and a Item will be filled with it.

I copied the same spider exactly, and replaced "example.com" with another initial url.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
from stb.items import StbItem

class StbSpider(CrawlSpider):
    domain_name = "stb"
    start_urls = ['http://www.stblaw.com/bios/MAlpuche.htm']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/bios/.\w+\.htm', )), callback='parse', follow=True), )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = StbItem()
        item['JD'] = hxs.select('//td[@class="bodycopysmall"]').re('\d\d\d\d\sJ.D.')
        return item

SPIDER = StbSpider()
```

But my spider "stb" does not collect links from "/bios/" as it is supposed to do. It runs the initial url, scrapes the `item['JD']` and writes it on a file and then quits.

Why is it that `SgmlLinkExtractor` is ignored? The `Rule` is read because it catches syntax errors inside the `Rule` line.

Is this a bug? is there something wrong in my code? There are no errors except a bunch unhandled errors that I see with every run.

It would be nice to know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks for any clues. Am I misunderstanding what `SgmlLinkExtractor` is supposed to do?

Comment: When I see "There are no errors except a bunch unhandled errors that I see with every run," I have to scratch my head.

Comment: Sorry, I see Deprecation Warnings. The errors that I was seeing were due to having telnet and shell open at the same time as mentioned by Pablo Hoffman here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767553/twisted-errors-in-scrapy-spider and when I closed the shell, I don't see them any more. Any clues why allowed links are not scraped?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `parse` function is actually implemented and used in the CrawlSpider class, and you're unintentionally overriding it. If you change the name to something else, like `parse_item`, then the Rule should work.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a very simple python spider and that works for me.

Comment: Interestingly, I have the same problem. When I change it to something else however, get an "Not Implemented Error" for "parse".

Comment: Are you inheriting from CrawlSpider? If not, then you do need a method named "parse".