# Getting an exception error when crawling with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am starting to test Scrapy in order to crawl a site but when I test my code I get an error which I can't seem to understand how to solve.

Here is the error output:

```
...
2012-12-18 02:07:19+0000 [dmoz] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://MYURL.COM> (referer: None)
2012-12-18 02:07:19+0000 [dmoz] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://MYURL.COM>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1178, in mainLoop
        self.runUntilCurrent()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/base.py", line 800, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 368, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 464, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spider.py", line 57, in parse
        raise NotImplementedError
    exceptions.NotImplementedError: 

2012-12-18 02:07:19+0000 [dmoz] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2012-12-18 02:07:19+0000 [dmoz] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 357,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 20704,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 18, 2, 7, 19, 595977),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
     'log_count/ERROR': 1,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 18, 2, 7, 18, 836322)}
```

It looks this might have to do with my `parse` function and the callback. I tried removing the `rule` and it worked but just for 1 single URL and what I need is to crawl the whole site.

Here is my code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from tutorial.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item


class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    start_urls = ["http://MYURL.COM"]
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=('http://MYURL.COM', )), callback='parse_l', follow=True),)


    def parse_l(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//div[@class=\'content\']')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = DmozItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('//div[@class=\'gig-title-g\']/h1').extract()
           item['link'] = site.select('//ul[@class=\'gig-stats prime\']/li[@class=\'queue \']/div[@class=\'big-txt\']').extract()
           item['desc'] = site.select('//li[@class=\'thumbs\'][1]/div[@class=\'gig-stats-numbers\']/span').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return items
```

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264829/why-does-scrapy-throw-an-error-for-me-when-trying-to-spider-and-parse-a-site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer with this question:

[Why does scrapy throw an error for me when trying to spider and parse a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264829/why-does-scrapy-throw-an-error-for-me-when-trying-to-spider-and-parse-a-site)

It looks like the `BaseSpider` does not implement the `Rule`

If you stumble upon this question and you are using `BaseSpider` to crawl you need to change it to `CrawlSpider` and import it as documented in http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html with

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
```

Comment: My code is similar to the one posted above and I am using `from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule` still I am getting the same error, how to rectify it ?
**EDIT:**
I am trying come up with site graph of the given url