# Using python scrapy based crawler but getting error

Tags: python, django

Hi folks I have written a crawler in python for scraping......

```
import scrapy

from c2.items import C2Item

try:

    class C2(scrapy.Spider):
            name = 'cn'
            allowed_domains = ['priceraja.com']
            start_urls = ['https://www.priceraja.com']



            def parse_item(self, response):

               Item = []
               Item['url']=response.xpath('//a/@href/text()').extract()
               yield Item

except Exception:
logging.exception("message")
```

I keep on getting NotImplemented error

```
2017-08-05 01:12:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing 
<GET 
https://www.killerfeatures.com> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Ana\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _ 
runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "D:\Ana\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in 
parse raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2017-08-05 01:12:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-08-05 01:12:28 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 435,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
```

'downloader/response_bytes': 9282,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 4, 19, 42, 28, 837000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 4, 19, 42, 25, 976000)}
  2017-08-05 01:12:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Comment: File "D:\Ana\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2017-07-05 23:54:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished) is the error I get

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post to include the error message, instead of posting it as a comment? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy is looking for the parse function while you have implement the parse_item function. Changing parse_item to parse might work, or you can override the parse function.

Another solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264829/why-does-scrapy-throw-an-error-for-me-when-trying-to-spider-and-parse-a-site) is to use CrawlSpider

Comment: Changed code as per suggestion still not working . Can someone add a working example and also scrapy version