# How to follow link with scrappy

Tags: python, scrapy

How to follow links in this example : http://snippets.scrapy.org/snippets/7/  ?
The script stop after visiting the link of the first page.

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
"""Our ad-hoc spider"""
name = "myspider"
start_urls = ["http://stackoverflow.com/"]

question_list_xpath = '//div[@id="content"]//div[contains(@class, "question-summary")]'

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    for qxs in hxs.select(self.question_list_xpath):
        loader = XPathItemLoader(QuestionItem(), selector=qxs)
        loader.add_xpath('title', './/h3/a/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('summary', './/h3/a/@title')
        loader.add_xpath('tags', './/a[@rel="tag"]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('user', './/div[@class="started"]/a[2]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('posted', './/div[@class="started"]/a[1]/span/@title')
        loader.add_xpath('votes', './/div[@class="votes"]/div[1]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('answers', './/div[contains(@class, "answered")]/div[1]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('views', './/div[@class="views"]/div[1]/text()')

        yield loader.load_item()
```

i've tried to change :

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
```

To

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider)
```

And add

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()),
         callback='parse',follow=True),
)
```

But it doesn't crawl all the site

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to subclass CrawlSpider, and rename `parse` function to something like `parse_page`, because CrawlSpider uses `parse` to start scraping.
[This was already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2074821/1052325)