# port error in scrapy

Tags: twisted, scrapy, web-crawler

I have designed a crawler where there will be two spiders.I have designed these using scrapy.
 These spiders will run independently by fetching data from the database.

We are running these spiders using a reactor.As we know that we cannot run the reactor repeatedly
we give some 500+ links to the second spider to crawl.
If we do like this we have a problem of port error. i.e scrapy is using only single port

```
Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.start_listening of <scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole instance at 0x0467B440>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1070, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 75, in start yield self.signals.send_catch_log_deferred(signal=signals.engine_started)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\signalmanager.py", line 23, in send_catch_log_deferred
return signal.send_catch_log_deferred(*a, **kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\signal.py", line 53, in send_catch_log_deferred
*arguments, **named)
--- <exception caught here> ---
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 137, in maybeDeferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\xlib\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 47, in robustApply
return receiver(*arguments, **named)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\telnet.py", line 47, in start_listening
self.port = listen_tcp(self.portrange, self.host, self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\reactor.py", line 14, in listen_tcp
return reactor.listenTCP(x, factory, interface=host)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 489, in listenTCP
p.startListening()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 980, in startListening
raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:6073: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

So what is the problem occuring here?? Then what is the optimal way to solve this scenario??Please help...

p.s: I have increased the number of ports in settings but it is always taking 6073 as default.

Comment: Can you show how are you running your spiders and how do you configure them?

Comment: is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767553/twisted-errors-in-scrapy-spider

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone No not same , I have disabled web and telnet consoles but its showing same error.

Comment: @alecxe `for url and arg in Database: #Db contains 500+ links`
            `obj.crawlRSSFeed(url,arg) #this function will start feedspider with 2 args`
         `reactor.run()` ---This reactor.run() is outside the for loop

Comment: @alecxe I think the problem is, i am passing 500+ urls to crawler and then starting the reactor.The code works fine if i pass less than 25 urls without any exception.. Since reactor cannot be restarted i have no choice but to send all the urls together and then start it.

Comment: What if you override `start_requests` methods of your spider and `yield` `Request`s in a loop?

Comment: You could use Scrapy's scheduling module http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html
to schedule your crawlers sequentially, avoid the issue of having hundred's gumming up the scheduler at a time.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way would be to disable the Telnet Console by adding this to your  `settings.py`:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
   'scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole': None
}
```

See also http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#extensions for a list of by-default enabled extensions.

Comment: It shows same set of errors even after adding Extensions to the settings.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem could be solved by running fewer concurrent crawlers. Here's a recipe I wrote for making requests sequentially:
This particular class only runs one crawler, but the modifications required to make it run batches (say 10 at a time) are trivial.

```
class SequentialCrawlManager(object):
    """Start spiders sequentially"""

    def __init__(self, spider, websites):
        self.spider = spider
        self.websites = websites
        # setup crawler
        self.settings = get_project_settings()
        self.current_site_idx = 0

    def next_site(self):
        if self.current_site_idx < len(self.websites):
            self.crawler = Crawler(self.settings)
            # the CSVs data in each column is passed as keyword arguments
            # the arguments come from the
            spider = self.spider() # pass arguments if desired
            self.crawler.crawl(spider)
            self.crawler.start()
            # wait for one spider to finish before starting the next one
            self.crawler.signals.connect(self.next_site, signal=signals.spider_closed)
            self.crawler.configure()
            self.current_site_idx += 1
        else:
            reactor.stop() # required for the program to terminate

    def start(self):
        log.start()
        self.next_site()
        reactor.run() # blocking call
```